# How do I implement a Telerik Custom Aggregate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, aggregate, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik Grid which has a footer that needs to display column sums. However, one of the colums' data types is `TimeSpan`, which isn't supported by Telerik's Sum aggregate. I need to use `GridBoundColumnBuilder.Aggregate()` to add the aggregates. **So I guess basically the question is how to reference my custom aggregate in telerik's Aggregate() method.** And if you notice anything else I'm doing wrong, feel free to point it out :)Using [this article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/designing-reports/implementing-custom-aggregate-functions.aspx), I created a class for my custom aggregate, called `SumAggregate`, shown below. (note that this isn't finished- its taken from the article. It actually implements a totally different aggregate)

**SumAggregate.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;

namespace TelerikPOC.CustomAggregates
{
    public class SumAggregate : AggregateFunction
    {
        private System.Collections.Generic.List<object> distinctValues;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the current aggregate function to its initial
        /// state ready to accumulate and merge values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method is called every time the accumulation of values 
        /// must start over for a new subset of records from the data source.
        /// </remarks>
        public void Init()
        {
            this.distinctValues = new System.Collections.Generic.List<object>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Accumulates new argument values to the current aggregate function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This aggregate function accepts one argument:
        /// number - a numeric value to accumulate to the aggregate function;
        /// </remarks>
        public void Accumulate(object[] values)
        {
            if (!distinctValues.Contains(values[0]))
            {
                distinctValues.Add(values[0]);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Merges the specified aggregate function to the current one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Aggregate">
        /// Specifies an aggregate function to be merged to the current one.
        /// </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method allows the reporting engine to merge two accumulated
        /// subsets of the same aggregate function into a single result.
        /// </remarks>
        public void Merge(AggregateFunction aggregate)
        {
            // Accumulate the values of the specified aggregate function.
            System.Collections.Generic.List<object> sums1 =     ((SumAggregate)aggregate).distinctValues;
            foreach (object o in sums1)
            {
                this.Accumulate(new object[] { o });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the currently accumulated value of the aggregate function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The currently accumulated numeric value of the aggregate function.
        /// </returns>
        public object GetValue()
        {
            return this.distinctValues.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for adding the aggregates. This conflicts with the code below from **index.cshtml**, but I wanted to include both methods of adding aggregates just to give more options on the answer. This needs to be modified to use a custom aggregate rather than a built-in one, like it is using now.

**GridHelper.cs** (unfinished -- will add logic to loop through the columns and such later. By the way, if anyone would like to help me out with *that* too, I'd be very grateful, though I'll admit I haven't tried anything yet.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent;
using TelerikPOC.CustomAggregates;

namespace TelerikPOC.Helpers
{
    public class GridHelper
    {
        public static void AddAggregateToColumn(GridBoundColumnBuilder<dynamic> columnBuilder, string Aggregate)
        {
            switch (Aggregate)
            {
                case "Sum":
                    {
                        columnBuilder.Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Sum())
                            .GroupFooterTemplate(result => "Sum:" + result.Sum)
                            .ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: <#= Sum #>")
                            .FooterTemplate(result => "Total: " + result.Sum);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I'm using the `HtmlHelper` class to build/render the telerik grid, like this:

From **Index.cshtml**: (be sure to read the comments to the right)

```
@{
    Html.Telerik()
    .Grid(Model)
    .Name("statisticalGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.PlanID).Aggregate(something);         //This is probably going to be where 
        columns.Bound(o => o.SessionID).Aggregate(something);      //I need the help. Just not sure
        columns.Bound(o => o.TimeSpan).Aggregate(something);       //how to reference the custom
        columns.Bound(o => o.TimeSpanDouble).Aggregate(something); //aggregate here, in
    })                                                             //place of `something`
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.Enabled(true))
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(page => page.PageSize(25))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Groupable(groupable => groupable.Enabled(true))
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnColumnReorder("onReorder"))
    .Render();
}
```

So I guess basically the question is how to reference my custom aggregate in telerik's `Aggregate()` method. And if you notice anything else I'm doing wrong, feel free to point it out :)

Edit: Just noticed that I have to implement the method `CreateAggregateExpression(Expression, bool)` in the SumAggregate class. Not entirely sure how to implement it, though.

Last Edit: I use a custom column builder method to build out the columms, so I'm not sure exactly how to do the formatting here. I was able to format the sum, but not the rest of the column, since outside the context of the telerik call I don't have access to the `item` variable. Here is basically what my column building logic is like:

In the telerik code,

```
.Columns(a => GridHelper.GenerateColumns(a, Model.SelectedReport))
```

And generate columns looks something like:

```
public static void GenerateColumns(GridColumnFactory<dynamic> columnFactory, Company.Project.Data.Entity.Report reportStructure)
        {
            foreach (var columnLayout in reportStructure.ReportCols.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnSequence))
            {
                GridBoundColumnBuilder<dynamic> columnBuilder = columnFactory.Bound(columnLayout.ColumnType);
                //do other stuff here (add aggregates, formatting, etc)
            }
```

So how would I do the formatting in this context?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need custom aggregates. You said one of the colums' data types is TimeSpan, but you don't have to display aggregates on every column. The code you have for custom aggregates is for Telerik Reporting. I'm not sure it will work with MVC. I would try doing regular aggregating following this model: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregatesserverside.

Comment: @Daniel Well I need custom aggregates because telerik's Sum aggregate for some reason can't handle TimeSpans. So I just need to be able to add up the timespans and have the total in the footer

Comment: I would still try to use regular aggregates if I could. It is true that you can't sum TimeSpans, but you can have another column that represents the TimeSpans in hours or days or whatever period makes sense for your project. Then it could have a sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is add another column that represents the TimeSpan in "Days". Then you would not have to use custom aggregates.

Model:

```
public List<Objects.Temp> GetTemp()
{
  List<Objects.Temp> ltemp = new List<Objects.Temp>();
  System.Random r = new Random();
  Objects.Temp t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "One";
  t.start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(25) - t.start;
  t.tsDays = t.ts.Days;
  ltemp.Add(t);
  t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "Two";
  t.start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(15) - t.start;
  t.tsDays = t.ts.Days;
  ltemp.Add(t);
  t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "Three";
  t.start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(55) - t.start;
  t.tsDays = t.ts.Days;
  ltemp.Add(t);

  return ltemp;
}
```

View:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(o => o.Name)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total Count: @item.Count</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Count: @item.Count</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.start)
            .Width(200)
            .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Max())
      //.Format("{0:c}")
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.Value)
            .Width(200)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Average())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.ts)
            .Width(100)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count().Min().Max())
            .FooterTemplate(
            @<text>
                <div>Min: @item.Min</div>
                <div>Max: @item.Max</div>
            </text>)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>@item.Title: @item.Key (Count: @item.Count)</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.tsDays)
          .Width(100)
          .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Sum())
          .FooterTemplate(
          @<text>
                <div>Sum: @item.Sum Days</div>
            </text>)
          .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>@item.Title: @item.Key (Sum: @item.Sum)</text>);
  })
    .Sortable()
```

)

You get something that looks like this:

[image]

**Version 2**

I updated my answer so that there is only one TimeSpan column with sums the TimeSpan and displays it in TimeSpan format. The data in the column is really TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds, but it displays as TimeSpan by using a template and formatting a TimeSpan using the TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds method. I think this way doing it is easier than creating a custom aggregate class if that is even possible with MVC extensions.

Model:

```
public class Temp
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan ts { get; set; }
  public double tsMilliseconds { get; set; }
}


  List<Objects.Temp> ltemp = new List<Objects.Temp>();
  System.Random r = new Random();
  Objects.Temp t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "One";
  t.Start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(25) - t.Start;
  t.tsMilliseconds = t.ts.TotalMilliseconds;
  ltemp.Add(t);
  t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "Two";
  t.Start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(15) - t.Start;
  t.tsMilliseconds = t.ts.TotalMilliseconds;
  ltemp.Add(t);
  t = new Objects.Temp();
  t.Name = "Three";
  t.Start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Value = r.NextDouble();
  t.ts = DateTime.Today.AddDays(55) - t.Start;
  t.tsMilliseconds = t.ts.TotalMilliseconds;
  ltemp.Add(t);
```

View:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(o => o.Name)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total Count: @item.Count</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Count: @item.Count</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.Start)
            .Template(@<text>@item.Start.ToShortDateString()</text>)
            .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Max())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.Value)
            .Width(200)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Average())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.tsMilliseconds)
          .Width(100)
          .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Sum())
          .Template(@<text>@TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@item.tsMilliseconds)</text>)
          .Title("TimeSpan")
          .FooterTemplate(
          @<text>
                <div>Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( @Convert.ToDouble( @item.Sum.Value.ToString() ) ) </div>
            </text>)
          //header if you group by TimeSpan
          .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>@item.Title: @item.Key (Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Sum.Value.ToString())))</text>)
          //footer for grouping
          .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Sum.Value.ToString()))</text>);
  })
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable(settings => settings.Groups(groups => groups.Add(o => o.Start)))
)
```

Without grouping produces this:

[image: TimeSpan Aggregate]

With grouping produces this:

[image: With Grouping]

Comment: Looks close, but I need the times displayed as timespans with their sum in the footer of *that* column. I can't have an extra column. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I updated my answer so there is a sum in the footer of the TimeSpan column displayed as a TimeSpan.

Comment: And will this still work even if there is grouping/sorting enabled?

Comment: by the way, this is a fantastic answer already. I appreciate all the help so far

Comment: Yes, it works with grouping / sorting enabled. I updated the answer to show grouping. It already had sorting.

Comment: You're a freakin wizard. Many thanks, and as soon as I can add a bounty to the question/your answer i will

Comment: Last question (and please, don't spend your time coming up with a kick-ass example for this) but you wouldn't foresee any issues with this method when using a dynamic data source, would you?

Comment: The control doesn't know whether the data is dynamic or static. I did it this way so you could more easily play with it if you wanted. Actually, the data is somewhat dynamic since it uses random numbers for Value and DateTime.Today for Start. But it should work the same with data from a database or pulled from a feed. If you are satisfied with the answer, could you accept it by clicking the check mark?

Comment: Well, I meant dynamic in the sense that it may use 10-15 totally different models, resulting in dramatically different charts. But I think your solution (well, a variant of your solution) is going to work. And i mean, I can, but if I select yours as accepted right now then I can't give you the bounty...

Comment: I'm not sure I can picture using 10-15 totally different models unless they have the same fields that are defined in the chart...  I didn't know that was how the bounty worked. Thanks.

Comment: Well, In my *real* project (the above is just a POC), I add columns dynamically to the chart based on the model,using reflection, type checking, etc. The model is of type IEnumerable<dynamic>. I would add a little of the code just to show you, but it doesn't really go with the question.

Comment: And I only took away your upvote temporarily, because I'm thinking that may prevent me from putting the bounty on the question, as I'm not seeing the bounty link

Comment: No problem. I saw on the faq that it said, "Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty." Maybe that is why there is no link.

Comment: Hey, see my last edit before you read this. Anyway I'm having some trouble formatting my column, since I build the telerik grid a little differently than normal. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a hard time visualizing this without seeing code. If you don't mind having an example in public of the type of thing you are doing, maybe you could add a new question with code examples.

Comment: there ya go. I greatly appreciate any help you can offer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036227/telerik-grid-custom-column-building-formatting

Comment: you made my day! Thank you!