# Telerik grid custom column building/formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid with a dynamic data source (the grid may use up to roughly 10 totally different models for its data), so I have to build the columns dynamically as well (obviously). One of the columns in the grid (with certain models) is a double representing a time span in milliseconds. ***What I want to do is format this double to look like a timespan***.The telerik code looks like this:

```
<% Html.Telerik()
     .Grid(Model.DynamicGridDataSource)
     .Name("statisticalGrid")
     .Columns(a => GridHelper.GenerateColumns(a, Model.SelectedReport))
     .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_SelectGrid", "Reports", new { reportId = Model.ReportId, dateFrom = Model.DateFrom, dateTo = Model.DateTo, date = Model.Date, AvailablePlans = Model.AvailablePlans }))
     .Sortable(GridSortSettingsBuilder => GridHelper.SortColumns(GridSortSettingsBuilder,
                                            Model.DynamicGridDataSource.GetType(),
                                            Model.SelectedReport))
     .Filterable()
     .Pageable(page => page.PageSize(25))
     .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
     .Groupable
     (
         groupingSettingsBuilder => GridHelper.GroupColumns(groupingSettingsBuilder,
                                    Model.DynamicGridDataSource.GetType(),
                                    Model.SelectedReport)
     )
     .ClientEvents(events => events
          .OnColumnReorder("onReorder"))
     .Render();
```

and GridHelper.GenerateColumns looks something like this:

```
public static void GenerateColumns(GridColumnFactory<dynamic> columnFactory, Company.Product.Data.Entity.Report reportStructure)
        {
            foreach (var columnLayout in reportStructure.ReportCols.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnSequence))
            {
                var columnBuilder = columnFactory.Bound(columnLayout.ColumnType);

                if (columnLayout.ColumnType.Equals("SessionLength") ||
                 columnLayout.ColumnType.Equals("AverageTime") ||
                 columnLayout.ColumnType.Equals("TotalTime") ||
                 columnLayout.ColumnType.Equals("CallTime"))
                {
                    // disable grouping
                    columnBuilder.Groupable(false);
                    string dataBindProperty = columnLayout.ColumnType;
                    if (columnLayout.DataFormat == "{0:T}")
                    {
                        //Even though the format looks like time ({0:T}), its actually a double which needs to be formatted here to look like a TimeSpan
                    }

                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnLayout.Label))
                {
                    columnBuilder.Title(columnLayout.Label);
                }

                if (columnLayout.DataFormat != null && columnLayout.DataFormat == "{0:P}")
                {
                    columnBuilder.Format("{0:P}");
                }

                if (columnLayout.SumIndicator)
                {
                    if (columnLayout.DataFormat == "{0:T}")
                    {
                        AddAggregateToColumnTimeSpan(columnBuilder, Aggregate.Sum);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddAggregateToColumn(columnBuilder, Aggregate.Sum);
                    }
                }

                if (columnLayout.HideIndicator)
                {
                    columnBuilder.Column.Hidden = true;
                }

            }
        }
```

I was able to format the footer correctly, but I didn't know how to format the rest of the column, since out of the context of the telerik code I don't have access to the `item` iterator or anything. Any suggestions/ideas? Maybe `columnFactory.Bound(columnType).Format(/*something*/)`?

Comment: I don't know if you can just use format. Is there a way to use a template like the Telerik grid? That way you can keep the double so that you can sum while still being able to display the double as a TimeSpan by converting in the template.

Comment: @Daniel Well I'm not sure! Theres GridColumnFactory.Template but that'd be for the whole grid, right? There's also columnBuilder.Template(), which seems a little closer to what I want. Not sure how I would write the template, though. Maybe thats where you could help.

Comment: Theres also clientTemplate, too. Not sure what the difference is

Comment: The columnBuilder.Template() sounds promising. ClientTemplate would be if you are using ajax, I think. I will try to look at this more tonight.

Comment: @Daniel thank you! I'm just not sure because there isn't really a way to access the data from inside the GridHelper class, and the template is gonna need a reference to the items in the column, right?

Comment: I have never used the GridHelper class before. If you can't access the data from inside the GridHelper class, I wonder if you can still define how the data should be handled for when the data is accessible.

Comment: @Daniel Thats because GridHelper is my class :) yeah, thats exactly my thinking. A template will be useless, since by the definition of a template its gonna need a reference to the data. And format would work, except I really need to do more of a conversion (milliseconds to hours:minutes:seconds) than a format. Looks like this may be a no-go.

Comment: Ha ha. I thought you were inheriting from a Telerik class. I guess it would only be possible to use a template without the data if the string were not evaluated until it is used in the grid. That would be a challenge in C#.

Comment: @Daniel, i think it'd be impossible, actually, since it'd largely be up to telerik to handle

Comment: @Daniel, the folks at telerik suggest that there is a possible workaround using DataBinding. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Using DataBinding in the GridHelper class or where?

Comment: @Daniel It'd be in the controller

Comment: But you need the controller to just give you the data. You need it to give you a double. The view is where the double is summed, but displayed as a TimeSpan. I don't see how doing anything in the controller would help.

Comment: I have been thinking about your issue, and I have an idea. Maybe it won't work for what you need, but I will put it in an answer so I can add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, "the grid may use up to roughly 10 totally different models for its data", so perhaps instead of trying to represent all those models in one grid, you have one grid for each model. You could put each grid in it's own partial view with the main view using some mechanism for deciding which partial view to load. Here is a simple example.

Controller

```
public ActionResult DynamicReport
{
    //Get your Model
    Model.model1 = model_01 = Model.DynamicGridDataSource.GetDynamicModel()
    //Get the name of what model is being returned so view knows which 
    //partial view to load
    ViewBag.Message = model_01.Name
    ...

    return View(model_01)
}
```

In the view have some conditional logic to chose which partial view to load.

View

```
<h2>View</h2>
@{
  string pView = "~/Views/Grid/Partial_01.cshtml";
  switch(ViewBag.Message)
  {
      case "p02":
      pView =  "~/Views/Grid/Parital_02.cshtml"
      break;
      .....
  }
}

@Html.Partial(pView)
```

PartialView_01

```
@model List<Models.Misc>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(a => a.Id).Width(120);
      columns.Bound(a => a.Name).Width(100);
      columns.Bound(a => a.Value).Format("{0:#,##0.00}").Width(100).Title("Price");
    })
)
```

PartialView_02

```
@model List<Models.Temp>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(o => o.Name)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total Count: @item.Count</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Count: @item.Count</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.Start)
            .Template(@<text>@item.Start.ToShortDateString()</text>)
            .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Max())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Max: @item.Max.Format("{0:d}")</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.Value)
            .Width(200)
            .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Average())
            .FooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>)
            .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Average: @item.Average</text>);

    columns.Bound(o => o.tsMilliseconds)
          .Width(100)
          .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Sum())
          .Template(@<text>@TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@item.tsMilliseconds)</text>)
          .Title("TimeSpan")
          .FooterTemplate(
          @<text>
                <div>Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Sum.Value.ToString())) </div>
            </text>)
      //header if you group by TimeSpan
          .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>@item.Title: @item.Key (Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Sum.Value.ToString())))</text>)
      //footer for grouping
          .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Sum: @TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Sum.Value.ToString()))</text>);
  })
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable(settings => settings.Groups(groups => groups.Add(o => o.Start)))
)
```

And so on, for each different model. With each model having its own partial view you can easily format each grid to fit its model while still having only one main view.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first thought too, but I think the reason we have it set up the way it is set up is because it makes it extremely easy to generate and implement new models on the fly. We use this for statistical reporting for a web site, so it often comes up that we have a new feature on the web site that we need to run reports on, and with the current set up it's as easy as making a model for it and passing it to the view.

Comment: Right, this would be a maintenance nightmare if your the shape of your data is constantly changing.

Comment: But I think you gave me an idea. I'm thinking about ***grouping*** the reports into 3 or 4 categories (maybe one for session-related stuff, one for activity related stuff, etc) and then letting each **group** (which would correspond to one partial view) contain all of the related columns. Then, within each group, each **report** would display only the columns specific to that report. That way, adding a new report would be a matter of adding a column or two to an existing group, or every once in a while adding a new group. That way it cuts down the maintenance substantially. What do you think?

Comment: I was wondering if your models had some natural groupings. I think it sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it's basically what I need